# Month To date -1 year for comparing results

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, count, between

I would like to compare stats between this month and this month last year
I am using sql database Here is my code that gives me Month to date

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN (MONTH(pm.DateAppIssued) = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND YEAR(pm.DateAppIssued) = YEAR(GETDATE()))  then 1 end) AS [Issued]
```

This will give me a number of Issued cases for `01/09/2016 - Getdate()`
What i want is the number of Issued cases for last year `01/09/2015 - 30/09/2015`
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove 1 from `YEAR(GETDATE())`

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN (MONTH(pm.DateAppIssued) = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND
                  YEAR(pm.DateAppIssued) = YEAR(GETDATE())-1)  
      then 1 end) AS [Issued]
```

Comment: Raphael now i feel stupid, i had it in my mind that if i removed 1 from year that it would mess up the months. Works great thanks

Comment: We all feel supid someday ;)